# C++ perfect forwarding in nested lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, perfect-forwarding

I have a case where I am constructing a special thread object.  This object must take a callable in the same way the std::thread does, do some validation, and then wrap it in another function which does some additional things (exact rationale is complicated and not relevant to this question).  I have a working solution but I am not convinced that it is optimal as I have not managed to get perfect forwarding working.

I created the following example to debug the issue and try to understand what my error is.

The example compiles and runs without issue.  However googletest's address sanitizer gives me this error:

> AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffcea0a8ff0 at pc 0x00000052a019 bp 0x7fee283febb0 sp 0x7fee283feba8

In the example I have a function called `safe_function_executer`. In this safe function the outermost lambda captures the function and arguments by value.  I also have a function called `bad_function_executer` in which I attempt perfect forwarding by capturing the function and arguments by reference.

Googletest's address sanitizer does not throw an error for the `safe_function_executer` but it does for the `bad_function_excecuter`.

I am having difficulty understanding where I am accessing a value that has gone out of scope in this example.  Does anyone know why Googletest's address sanitizer would be throwing this error?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

//!!!WARNING Contrived Example Follows!!!

template<class SomeType, class F, class ...Args>
void a_function_running_function( SomeType& some_arg, F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    *some_arg = 42;
}

template<class SomeType, class F, class ...Args>
std::thread safe_function_executer( SomeType& some_arg, F&& f, Args&&... args )
{
    return std::thread( [=]() mutable { 
        a_function_running_function( some_arg, [&]() mutable {
            f( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); });});

}   


template<class SomeType, class F, class ...Args>
std::thread bad_function_executer( SomeType& some_arg, F&& f, Args&&... args )
{
    return std::thread( [&,some_arg]() mutable { 
        a_function_running_function( some_arg, [&]() mutable {
            f( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); });});

}

void some_function(int arg1, bool arg2, std::tuple<int,bool>& ret)
{
    std::get<0>(ret) = arg1;
    std::get<1>(ret) = arg2;
}

int main()
{
    auto arg = std::make_shared<std::atomic<int>>(0);
    auto ret = std::tuple<int,bool>{0, false};

    //works (but not perfectly forwarded?)
    auto good_thread = safe_function_executer( arg, &some_function,
                                               45, true, ret ); 
    good_thread.join();

    //address sanitizer errors
    auto bad_thread = bad_function_executer( arg, &some_function,
                                             45, true, ret );
    bad_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: There are a few include headers and googletest macro's I have to add to allow googletest to do it's things but none of the functions (save for the main which is replaced with a googletest TEST function) are modified.  I do not deny that this may be a false positive but I want to be sure.  Someone more experienced with lambdas and perfect-forwarding may see an issue, I do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the parameters you are passing to `bad_function_executer` are temporaries and go out of scope in your main thread as soon as `bad_function_executer` returns. The temporaries are gone but you still use a reference to them in your lambda in the other thread.

In your good version, you capture the `args` by value, making a local copy of them, which stays around through the lifetime of the lambda.

If you made them all lvalues and passed them in that way, then they would remain in scope until the join() call, which would allow things to work with `bad_function_executer`.

```
int arg1 = 45;
bool arg2 = true;
//address sanitizer errors
auto bad_thread = bad_function_executer( arg, &some_function,
                                         arg1, arg2, ret );
```

but I think you're better off just capturing by value in this case, as you do with your `good` version.

Comment: Hmm...  Getting rid of the std::ref did change the error.  Now it says " AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffcea0a8ff0 at pc 0x00000052a019 bp 0x7fee283febb0 sp 0x7fee283feba8".  Updating question...

Comment: @NathanOwen well, all the parameters are temporaries... the `45` and the `true` are as well.  Just realized that.

Comment: The 45 and true are rvalues so they should be move constructed (if I understand correctly, which clearly I don't)

Comment: std::ref() is an rvalue, too.   That does not move construct anything.   You are storing rvalue references to the rvalues and references (even rvalue references) are just like pointers and must refer/point to a valid object.

Comment: That would be a problem...  So is the solution then to have the outer lambda capture by value and then use std::ref or std::cref anywhere that I want to pass in a reference to an lvalue?

Comment: yes.  If you have an expensive object you want to pass in, you can pass it in with a  std::ref() which gets copied by value cheap.  That approach gives you the most control of how your parameters get passed in and what their lifetimes are.

Comment: Hrmmm... however this kinda breaks your perfect forwarding.   What you need to do is be able to perfect forward into the lambda and then perfect forward out of that into the function.   I don't know how to do that.

Comment: THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT:  https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/capturing_perfectly_forwarded_objects_in_lambdas.html  turns out it's hard.